# How to add watermark to pdf file?

Tags: python, django

How to add watermark to pdf file generated from this code?

```
import xhtml2pdf
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def delivery_cancel(request, did):
    d_instance = get_object_or_404(Delivery, pk=did, user=request.user)
    users = request.user.get_profile()
    user = request.user
    contents = render_to_string('delivery_cancel.html', {'delivery':d_instance,'users':users,'user':user})
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=mypdf.pdf'
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(contents.encode('utf-8')), result, show_error_as_pdf=True, encoding='UTF-8')
    response.write(result.getvalue())
    result.close()
    return response
```

I tried to use reportlab but I failed so I'm asking for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to `xhtml2pdf` is XHTML, so you probably want to specify your watermark there. The documentation [says to use a `background-image` on `@page`](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/usage.rst#page-background-image).

Alternatively, you can create a single-page PDF that just contains the watermark and apply it to your generated file after the fact using something like [`pdftk`'s `background` option](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-background).

Answer (score 0):

My approach is a longer one but it should solve most of the problems faced.
With this script you will be able to add the list of watermark email address from a xlsx sheet and add the same email address as watermark to all the pages of a pdf which you input

```
# Importing all required packages
import xlrd
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor

# create watermarked booklet
def final_booklets(file_name,booklet):
    watermark_obj = PdfFileReader(file_name)
    watermark_page = watermark_obj.getPage(0)
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(booklet)
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    # Watermark all the pages
    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        page = pdf_reader.getPage(page)
        page.mergePage(watermark_page)
        pdf_writer.addPage(page)
    output = file_name+"_booklet.pdf"
    with open(output, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

# Create watermark pdf again each email address
def watermark_pdf(target,booklet):
    file_name = (target + ".pdf")
    c = canvas.Canvas(file_name)
    c.saveState()
    c.setFillColor(HexColor('#dee0ea'))
    c.setFont("Helvetica", 40)
    c.translate(15*cm, 20*cm )
    c.rotate(45)
    c.drawRightString(0,0,target)
    c.restoreState()
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    final_booklets(file_name,booklet)

# Read the sheet to get everyones email address
def read_xlsx(fn):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(fn)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    booklet = "book.pdf"
    for cell in range(1,sheet.nrows):
        target = sheet.cell(cell,1).value
        watermark_pdf(target,booklet)

# main controller
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fn = "Test.xlsx"
    read_xlsx(fn)
```

Original Github link: https://github.com/manojitballav/python_watermark/blob/master/master.py